# How to add existing songs to a music library Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

What I'm trying to do is add songs that artists have already uploaded to a user library (I have already set up my app so that artists can upload songs). Also, I have set up my code so that an empty user library is created after a user signs up (using the after_create Active Record Callback).

To be more clear, I would like for the user to be able to add songs they see within the site to their library.

However, this is escaping me. I am familiar with CRUD, and have an idea how I would create a library and add existing songs to it, but I am not quite sure how I could add a song to a user library by clicking a button/link saying "Add Song To Library" which would be next to a song, and having it add to the user's existing empty library.

My existing code is below.

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :meta, polymorphic: true

  before_create :create_empty_profile

  after_create :create_empty_library #may not be the best way to do it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

  acts_as_messageable

  has_many :playlists

  has_many :user_friendships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friends, -> { where(user_friendships: { state: 'accepted'}) }, through: :user_friendships
  has_many :pending_user_friendships, -> { where ({ state: 'pending' }) }, class_name: 'UserFriendship', foreign_key: :user_id
  has_many :pending_friends, through: :pending_user_friendships, source: :friend

  has_many :chat_rooms, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :chat_messages, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy

  mount_uploader :profile_pic, ProfilePicUploader

    def mailboxer_name
      self.name
    end

    def mailboxer_email(object)
      self.email
    end

  def admin?
    role == 'admin'
  end

  def moderator?
    role == 'moderator'
  end

  def create_empty_profile
    if is_artist?
      profile = ArtistProfile.new
    else
      profile = UserProfile.new
    end
    profile.save(validate: false)
    self.meta_id = profile.id
    self.meta_type = profile.class.name
  end

  def create_empty_library
    library = Library.new
    library.user_id = self.id
    library.save(validate: false)
  end

end
```

Library.rb:

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :library_songs
  has_many :songs, through: :library_songs

  has_many :library_albums
  has_many :albums, through: :library_albums
end
```

library_song.rb

```
class LibrarySong < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :library
  belongs_to :song
end
```

library_album.rb

```
class LibraryAlbum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :library
  belongs_to :album
end
```

libraries_controller.rb

```
class LibrariesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @libraries = Library.all
  end

  def show
    @library = Library.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I was able to create playlists and add songs to them using the form/controller below.

playlists/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>New Playlist</h1>

<%= form_for(@playlist) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <% Song.all.each do |song| -%>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag :song_ids, song.id, false, :name => 'playlist[song_ids][]', id: "song-#{song.id}" %>
      <%= song.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

playlists_controller.rb:

```
class PlaylistsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @playlists = Playlist.all
  end

  def show
    @playlist = Playlist.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @playlist = Playlist.new
  end

  def create
    @playlist = Playlist.create(playlist_params)
    redirect_to @playlist
  end

  private

  def playlist_params
    params.require(:playlist).permit(:name, song_ids: [])
  end
end
```

However, the main issue is that in the form above, the playlist is being created along with the existing songs. In this case, I would need to add existing songs to an existing library that is empty.

Any ideas, guys? This would be very helpful. I would be happy to upload any code needed.

Comment: I don't fully get what you mean by `the playlist is being created along with the existing songs. In this case, I would need to add existing songs to an existing library that is empty`

Comment: In the playlists/new.html.erb form, I am creating a playlist and choosing the songs to be added to the playlist at the same time. I would need to be able to add an existing song to a library that has already been created prior. (i.e. when a user signs up, a library is created, but it is empty). Once that user browses the site, they should be able to add songs they see on the site to that same library.

Comment: are you interchanging the usage of `playlists` and `library`?

Comment: No. Users have playlists and libraries. Like iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you don't actually have has_many :libraries set in your user model. Judging by your Library model, I think this was what you had intended. You should really just create the 'new' models before you save the User model. You could use something similar to this and do it all in one action.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.build_full_user(params, songs)
    # Assign all normal attributes here
    new_user = User.new
    new_user.name = params[:name]

    # If you want to assign new songs, just make a new Library model and associate them. 
    new_library = Library.new

    # Build the song models if you haven't found/created or passed them in already.
    new_songs = Songs.build_songs_from_list(songs) 
    new_library.songs << new_songs

    new_user.libraries << new_library

    # You can do the save check here or up one level if you'd like. 
    return new_user
  end
end
```